# Superposition of Sine and Cosine functions

Tags: trigonometry

I was wondering this:

Let a and b be real numbers. Is it always possible to find real numbers c, d, and e such that $$a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)=c\cos\left(\frac{x+d}e\right)$$
Why is this the case?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *ccos*?

Comment: @DonAntonio Fixed. Just a problem in viewing.

Comment: Next time try \cos , \sin , \tan\ for the trigonometric fucntions with LaTeX

Comment: @experimentX Why is this the case? Could you post an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \sin{x} + \dfrac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \cos{x} \right)\\
=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\sin{\varphi} \sin{x} + \cos{\varphi} \cos{x} \right)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos{(x-\varphi)},$$ where
$$\sin{\varphi} =\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}, \\
\cos{\varphi} =\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)= \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \left( \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\sin(x) +  \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\cos(x)\right)$$

Then let $\tan(\phi) = \frac{a}{b}$ and see what you get for $\sin(\phi)$ and $\cos(\phi)$